# Need to add meta tags in custom page created by custom module

Tags: 7

I have installed ["Tagadelic"](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagadelic) module.Then I created one custom module to display tag clouds in a page.
Now I need to add/modify meta description for this page only.
So what is the process for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also install the [context](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fcontext&ei=2yBLVblLiaxT9uWA4AI&usg=AFQjCNFOHz4dSbZxJKJqw-4XPwg7fU-NdA&sig2=Ut8UPVqP2c51gQdLY-t5-A&bvm=bv.92765956,d.d24) module and the metatag context module to set meta tags by URL.

Just specify the URL, and enter the meta tags you wish to display.

Answer (score 2):

A programmatical solution could be to use something like this. you could put it in a preprocess hook in your template.php

```
$path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias();

  if ($path_alias == 'thepathofmypage') {
    $meta_head_blog = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
       '#markup' => '<meta name="title" content="My metatag title"><meta name="description" content="My metatag desc">',
);
drupal_add_html_head($meta_head_blog, 'metaHeadBlog');
```